# Azure functions v2 with ASP.NET Core Configuration (Database First)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to implement azure functions v2 with connections to a blob storage and an SQL Database.

There are a lot of packages that are not supported anymore; and I found out that `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration` is not supported anymore and that I need to use `ASP.NET Core Configuration`.

I tried implementing that as described in this [article](https://blog.jongallant.com/2018/01/azure-function-config/), but I keep getting an error inside the azure cli:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: QueueProcessor. QueueProcessorAzureFunction: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

Also when trying to access the sql database like usual:

```
using (var context =  new DBEntities)
{
[…]
}
```

I get another error in the cli:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: QueueProcessor. EntityFramework: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. EntityFramework: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What am I missing? Could anyone please help?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Requested code:

```
namespace QueueProcessorAzureFunction
{
public class StorageContext
{

    private CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;

    public StorageContext(ExecutionContext context)
    {

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();


        _storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(config.GetConnectionString("BlobStorage"));
    }

    public CloudBlobClient BlobClient
    {
        get { return _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient(); }
    }

    public CloudTableClient TableClient
    {
        get { return _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(); }
    }

    public CloudQueueClient QueueClient
    {
        get { return _storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient(); }
    }
}
}
```

Inside the queue trigger azure function:

```
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("stack", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
{
var storageContext = new StorageContext(context);

[…]
}
```

Inside the `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "[…]",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "BlobStorage": "[…]"
},
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBEntities": {
      "ConnectionString": "[…]",
      "ProviderName": "System.Data.EntityCLient"
  },
  "BlobStorage": "[…]"
 }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

OK, so the error occurs when I define var config; for now I'll simply pass the connection string in the Storage context constructor as such:

```
    public StorageContext(ExecutionContext context)
    {
        _storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("CompleteConnectionString");
    }
```

**EDIT 3**

So for the problem with the SQL Database, given that my database is in a second project, where I add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model; I'm not sure how I can resolve the problem.

From what I figured, in .NET Standard I need to use Dependencies Injection into the DB Context now. But given that I have a database first model, I don't have an DB context...

**EDIT 4**

Entity Framework Core... I guess you need to use Entity Framework Core with Azure function v2... try [THIS](https://dibranmulder.github.io/2018/08/23/Azure-functions-V2-with-EF-Core/).

**EDIT 5**

Ok.
First, trying to use Scaffold-DbContext with NuGet console to generate your DBContext in a .NET Standard project does not work. Consequently, Azure functions v2  that are of .NET Standard 2.0 can't actually use `Scaffold-Dbcontext` to generate their DbContext.

To work around that I made a second .Net Core project used the Scaffold-DBcontext command to generate the Dbcontext and the tables and then simply copied them to my Azure function project.
Actually I used the Developer Command prompt for VS, but I assume using NuGet console would be the same. Here is a useful link to do [it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NDE8wR5X_c).

Next you have to use dependency injection. And this is where I got sort of stuck... And that is due to NuGet packet version management. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsNSf5TG4yc) is useful link to understand how to implement Dependency Injection in azure functions.

Simply: After installing the package `AzureFunctions.Autofac.2.0.0` (NOTE THE VERSION), and `Autofac.4.8.1`, add a new class file (lets call it `config.cs`);Inside:

```
public class Config
{
    public Config()
    {
        DependencyInjection.Initialize(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterType<DBContext>();
        });
    }
}
```

Now you pass the Context as a parameter, such as `[Inject]DBContext context`, then you need to add `[DependencyInjectionConfig(typeof(AutofacConfig))]` right below the namespace and I guess you could access the Database now; using Linq I can write stuff like:
`var a = context.Studies.Where(s => s.Id == 10569).FirstOrDefault();`
This is why I assume this works.

Overall this is how my function looks like:

```
namespace FunctionApp10
{

[DependencyInjectionConfig(typeof(Config))]
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("queue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log, [Inject]DBContext context)
    {

        var a = context.Studies.Where(s => s.Id == 10569).FirstOrDefault();

    }
}
}
```

But when I build I get the error

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

And I guess that is because it is looking for version 2.1.0 while I have 3.0.0-beta5. I tried editing the csproj with no success.

Now if you try to download `AzureFunctions.Autofac.3.0.5` it uninstalls `Windows.Azure.Storage.8.6.0` and even if you reinstall it manually, you get errors like:

`The type or namespace name 'QueueTriggerAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

[My Issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/999) on GitHub.

That's about it... Hope someone figures it out.

Comment: Show how you tried to implement what was in the linked article

Comment: the second error is because you now have to pass the connection string/options to the db context if it will try to look for connection in default config which is what you are migrating away from.

Comment: While yes, you are adding more details, you need to provide a [mcve] that will help us properly assess the problem. There are too many gaps in *small* snippets of code you are currently provided for us to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hello @Nkosi Thank you for your reply. I have added all of the testing code that I have; this is basically all that I did to receive the error. The SQL database is added in a second class library project where I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model, then referenced that project in this one. Also I don't understand your initial comment, I do add the connection strings in of the SQL database in local.settings.json…

Comment: @A.JAlhorr Glad you solved it, could you post your edit4 as an answer so that it can help others? Edit info may be omitted in some quick search.

Comment: Sorry, cant really do that... Entity Framework Core is apparently the way to go, but I its not completely working for me (So I don't have an answer that worked for me). Autofac is causing some build errors. I will add an edit 5 to explain what I did, to maybe help someone get closer; but I will be stop working with azure function... At least for now. They are too unstable. And management told me Im taking too much time with the project :/ Thx a lot Microsoft...